# Unity3D: Is there a easy way to give a min/max to a value in the inspector?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to figure out how to give a minimum and maximum to a value in the inspector.

For example:

```
public float testValue;
```

I know I can set a minimum and maximum in the code with if/else statements, but that is going to be a mess with a lot of variables. This TestValue will be visibile in the Unity inspector.

I want to make it possible that the maximum of this value is 100 and the minimum is 0. Is there a fancy way to do this instead of a lot of statements?

Thanks in forward :)

Answer (score 8):

Check the [Range](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RangeAttribute-ctor.html) attribute:

use it like this:

```
[Range(0, 100)]
public float testValue;
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly where I was looking for

Comment: how to make it a int range?  @frankhermes

Comment: @ErnieSender `[Range(0, 100)] public int testValue;`

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
[Range (0f,100f)] public float testValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible this one

```
[Range(0.0f, 10.0f)]

public float mySliderFloat;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a fancy way to do this. With the Range declaration: `[Range(min, max)]`

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/tips/show-public-variables-sliders-rangemin-max